# delay the execution of code till the completion of a function in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my Angularjs application, I have code as shown below. Initially `$scope.changeChartTypeModelNames` array is empty but inside `$scope.doTimeConsumingTask`, I am populating `$scope.changeChartTypeModelNames` with some values. But the problem is happening due to the time consuming tasks inside `$scope.doTimeConsumingTask`. Even before `$scope.doTimeConsumingTask`  completes the next `for` `loop` is getting executed. So, I am always getting `$scope.changeChartTypeModelNames` length as Zero. Even though after the completion of `$scope.doTimeConsumingTask` the `$scope.changeChartTypeModelNames` array shows the correct values. Only  after completion of `$scope.doTimeConsumingTask`, I want the next for loop to be executed. How can I achieve it? Consider that `$scope.doTimeConsumingTask` may or may not have Ajax calls.

```
$scope.$watch('isTopCarrierListClosed', function (isTopCarrierListClosed) {
    if ($rootScope.isTopCarrierListClosed) {
        $scope.doTimeConsumingTask($scope.dataSet);
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.changeChartTypeModelNames.length; i++) {
            var dropDownName = $scope.changeChartTypeModelNames[i];
            alert(dropDownName);
            $scope.dropDownName = {};
        }
    }
}



$scope.doTimeConsumingTask = function(data){
     ...

     ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So you should use de defer object and `then` to complete your job.

For example, in your `doTimeConsumingTask` method :

```
function doTimeConsumingTask(){

    var def = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/some_url')
        .success(function(data){
            def.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
            def.reject('Failed to get todos');
        });

    return def.promise;
}
```

And in your main programm, you can use the `doTimeConsumingTask` as follow :

```
$scope.doTimeConsumingTask($scope.dataSet)
    .then(function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.changeChartTypeModelNames.length; i++) {
            var dropDownName = $scope.changeChartTypeModelNames[i];
            alert(dropDownName);
            $scope.dropDownName = {};
        },
        function(errorMsg){
            console.log(errorMsg);
        });
```

For information, here is the [angular doc of $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).
Hope help.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking into using [$q from Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), an implementation of promises/deferred objects inspired by [Kris Kowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Following the example from the documentation, (i used a different structure, but it should be clear) here's an implementation with comments:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  // your .module() and .controller()
  angular
    .module('app.carrier')
    .controller('Carrier', Carrier);

    // dependency injection
    Carrier.$inject = ['$q'];

    // the function with $q so we can use promises/deferred
    function Carrier($q) {

      var doTimeConsumingTask = function(data) {

        // get it so we can use it
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // demonstration flow of function calls 
        setTimeout(function() {      

          // seed some numbers between 1..10 to simulate 
          // resolve or reject by returning strings
          var seed = Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1;

          if(seed < 5) {
            deferred.resolve('OK');

          } else {
            deferred.reject('REJECTED');

          }   
        }, 1000);

        // now, this i promise you ( resolve or reject )
        return deferred.promise;
      };


      // lets call your function, it returns a..
      var promise = doTimeConsumingTask(someData);

      // like english, if you have a promise then 'resolved' otherwise 'rejected'
      promise.then(function(returnedString) {
        alert('Success: ' + returnedString); // "OK"

      }, function(reason) {
        alert('Failed: ' + reason); // "REJECTED"

      });
    } 

})();
```

This is 1 of 2 implementations (see docs).
Hope this helps.